# Search for and reverse engineer foreign key relationships in DB without foreign keys defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, erd

I've inherited a really old database with about 100 tables. I know there are foreign key relationships by looking through tables, but I've also determined that there are no relationships actually defined in the database.  Further, there are no consistent naming conventions.

I've tried just working it out by looking at tables and trying joins, but it has been time consuming and I just don't have that much time. So now I'm working on some automated ideas.

Has anyone ever tried to run a query on a database to find foreign keys?

My thoughts on the general logic of the query would be this:

For each table:
If it has a primary key, check to see if that key name exists in all other tables. If so, do a check to see if there is a high percentage match between the two sets of IDs. If so, output this as a potential FK relationship. Specify if it is one to one or one to many.

If the same name doesn't exist in the other tables, try searching all tables for fields with exactly the same data type. Try to see if there is a high percentage match in the two sets of IDs. If so, output this as a potential FK relationship. Specify if it is one to one or one to many.

I know this will likely lead to a lot of false positives, but it would be better than manually searching.

Is my logic sound here, or am I completely off base in trying to automate this search?

My eventual goal is to generate a ER diagram that I can use when building some new queries.

Using MSSQL

Comment: Doesn't need to be only Primary keys. You can key to a unique contraint.

Comment: If the relationship aren't defined, the only way you can find out what the relationships are is by existing knowledge or "exploring" the data. SQL Server will have no idea what the relationships are. I have to work with a database like this every day; there isn't a single foreign key in the table and the Primary Key values often don't exist in other tables; even those that *could* be candidates will have orphaned rows. How do we know what relationships exist? Our own documentation (not the vendors); something that is continually updated. Far from ideal, but what can happen with a DB from 1979.

Comment: Good point :)  I stand corrected. @dfundako

Comment: There really is no way to automate this. As you said you may get false positives. But you also are just as likely to miss critical relationships because the names are different. Spending a LOT of time in the database and exploring is about the only way to be close to certain. This type of database requires "tribal knowledge" and the only way to get that is time.

Comment: I don't see why something couldn't be automated- write something that digs through the information_schema.columns looking for columns that are the same type across two tables, and work out what percentage crossover they have in values with a left join - count() the left column and the right column and see what percentage you get from right/left

Comment: That is what I was thinking, maybe worth the effort. Hard to tell for sure. @CaiusJard

Comment: It's one of those things you might have to check by doing it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look for pairs:

```
SELECT * FROM
  information_schema.columns cl
  INNER JOIN
  information_schema.columns cr
  ON
    cl.table_name < cr.table_name AND
    cl.data_type = cr.data_type
```

This generates a list of every column in every table crossed with every other column in other tables, where the data types are equal. Hopefully using < on the table names means that `tableA.somenumber` will be paired with `tableB.someothernumber` but not the reverse (unless you actually want the reverse) - there isn't much point asking the db how many values in a equal b and then later asking how many in b equal a

Now let's make it write an SQL:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    'SELECT ''{Ltable}.{Lcol}'' as lefty, ''{Rtable}.{Rcol}'' as righty, count(l.{Lcol}) as countLefty, count(r.{Rcol}) as countRighty, case when count(r.{Rcol}) = 0 then 0 else count(l.{Lcol})/count(r.{Rcol}) end as percenty
     FROM {Ltable} l LEFT JOIN {Rtable} r ON l.{Lcol} = r.{Rcol} UNION ALL',
    '{Ltable}', cl.table_name),
    '{Rtable}', cr.table_name),
    '{Lcol}', cl.column_name),
    '{Rcol}', cr.column_name)
FROM
  information_schema.columns cl
  INNER JOIN
  information_schema.columns cr
  ON
    cl.table_name < cr.table_name AND
    cl.data_type = cr.data_type
```

If you run this SQL, it will generate a results grid that has an SQL in each row- copy it out the grid and paste it back into a query editor, remove the ultimate UNION ALL and then run it

On my reasonably small DB of 90 tables with ~8 columns in each it generated 62,000 combinations it wanted to do; use with caution.. Or set it going one night on the backup server and come back the next day

Comment: That's a really nifty nested replace statement. I like it. I didn't think of doing that.My run resulted in 2,678,538 rows. Maybe a good idea to run on the backup. :)

Comment: LOL. Wonderful They have keywords in some column names. Sigh. Thanks for your help, this should be interesting.

Comment: Definitely one of those cases where GUID IDs would be a boost, compared to incrementing INT IDs. I'd expect a guid based db to show a nice high percentage for any columns that were genuinely related and 0% go columns that weren't.. Incrmentin ints would be a lot more messy: best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Caius Jard for his awesome solution. I've expanded it to customize it for my needs. For those interested, here it is:

```
-- Setup types to ignore
DECLARE @ignore table (ignorefield varchar(20));

-- Note: Must ignore 'text', must also ignore any other blob data types used in db. Others are optional.
INSERT @ignore(ignorefield) values('char'),('datetime'),('money'),('image'),('bit'),('binary'),('text');

-- Write queries to find fields that are potential foreign keys
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    'SELECT ''{Ltable}.{Lcol}'' as lefty, ''{Rtable}.{Rcol}'' as righty, count(l.{Lcol}) as countLefty, count(r.{Rcol}) as countRighty, case when count(r.{Rcol}) = 0 then 0 else count(l.{Lcol})/count(r.{Rcol}) end as percenty
     FROM {Ltable} l LEFT JOIN {Rtable} r ON l.{Lcol} = r.{Rcol} UNION ALL',
    '{Ltable}', QUOTENAME(cl.table_name)),
    '{Rtable}', QUOTENAME(cr.table_name)),
    '{Lcol}', QUOTENAME(cl.column_name)),
    '{Rcol}', QUOTENAME(cr.column_name))
FROM
  information_schema.columns cl
  INNER JOIN
  information_schema.columns cr
  ON
    cl.table_name < cr.table_name AND
    cl.data_type = cr.data_type
WHERE
    cl.data_type NOT IN (SELECT ignorefield from @ignore)
    AND cl.is_nullable = 'NO' -- Maybe remove for some db designs.
ORDER BY
    cl.data_type ASC
```